# How to do a longform bootstrap with Angular 2?

Tags: angular

I've recently came across an article where someone wanted to use components freely (Angular 2) with Drupal as a backend service.

You can check out the article here: http://www.mediacurrent.com/blog/building-wundergroundcom-drupal-angular-2-challenge-1-how-bootstrap

Matt, mentions here how to get this done and shows us a Plunkr example, however it looks like that it's no longer working with the new Angular 2 RC1 version.

Can someone please update this Plunkr to work with the current version? I know that platform and bootstrap has been removed/placed to somewhere else and I think that's the reason it's not working.

Here is the plunker example:

http://plnkr.co/edit/A7fyFUST9IdP1FriauXk?p=preview

And here is the code that might need to be changed in my opinion:

```
//main entry point
import {platform} from 'angular2/core';
import {bootstrap, BROWSER_PROVIDERS, BROWSER_APP_PROVIDERS} from 'angular2/platform/browser';
import {Comp1} from './comp1';
import {Comp2} from './comp2';

var app = platform(BROWSER_PROVIDERS).application([BROWSER_APP_PROVIDERS]);

// These are just loaded manually, but could be put inside an isInViewport
// function for lazyloading.
app.bootstrap(Comp1);
app.bootstrap(Comp2);

bootstrap({Comp1, Comp2}, [])
  .catch(err => console.error(err));
```

I would really appreciate if someone could offer a viable solution here.

Comment: Just curious: what does "longform" mean in this context?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now is actually easier to do that:

```
import { bootstrap }    from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { AppTwoComponent } from './app2.component';

bootstrap(AppComponent);
bootstrap(AppTwoComponent);
```

working example -> http://plnkr.co/edit/sRMyTMYK8ba3NS2eQorR

But you will probably need to be able to communicate between applications:
http://plnkr.co/edit/aZqdJe3OZ8K2odHioWkB

```
var shared = new SharedService();//this way we share same instance

bootstrap(AppComponent, [{ provide: SharedService, useValue: shared }]);
bootstrap(App2Component, [{ provide: SharedService, useValue: shared }]);
```

and you can implement shared service according to:
https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html#!#bidirectional-service

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response} from '@angular/http';
import { Observable, Subject } from 'rxjs/Rx';

@Injectable()
export class SharedService {
  constructor() {
    console.log('shared service init');
  }
  // Observable string source
  private missionConfirmedSource = new Subject<string>();

  // Observable string stream
  missionConfirmed$ = this.missionConfirmedSource.asObservable();

  confirmMission(astronaut: string) {
    console.log(astronaut);
    this.missionConfirmedSource.next(astronaut);
  }
}
```

publish like this:

```
this._sharedService.confirmMission('some string');
```

subscribing looks like this:

```
_sharedService.missionConfirmed$.subscribe(
        hero => {
            console.log('confirmed');
            alert('App2Component received hero click: ' + hero);
        });
```

Comment: Unfortunately, somewhere after Angular 2 RC4 `bootstrap` was removed from `@angular/platform-browser-dynamic` (and its `bootstrapModule` expects, well, a module).